# Admob ad is not visible still error 2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

I have a problem with Admob in android app.
Every time on logcat am getting the dialogue ad is not visible, Not refreshing ad. Error Code 2 and Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.

Testing on Xiaomi Redmi note 2

in main activity.xml I have that code

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

I added to AndroidManifest.xml

and

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

Java code

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
                .addTestDevice("F362E9BD751EF0E1933B8FEEDDD2A0BD")  // An example device ID
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(request);


    }
}
```

What's more in build gradle I have compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'

So what can be wrong?

Comment: you should try without addTestDevice()  method. or check you network also.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added following code in

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mAdView.pause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mAdView.resume();
}
```

Disable your Ad blocker. Make sure you don't have an app like adBlock installed.

Anyway, that error means "Timed out waiting for ad response", so check your Internet connection and try changing from Wi-Fi to Mobile Network

**Update**

> in main activity.xml I have that code

Are you sure you have added `AdView` in `activity_main_menu.xml` layout not `activity.xml` because in your code your activity's layout is activity_main_menu. BTW layout name suggest that it is a layout for activity's menu not activity itself.

> setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);